# What is the best method for running PHP without an Internet connection?

Tags: php, mysql, testing, offline

I'm a university student, basically I created a php/mySQL app for school and I want to continue developing over the summer. Problem is, my summer job has no internet or cellular service. I will be living in a garage at a fishing shop with 4 other guys. Space is limited. I will be taking my MacBook Pro.

Option 1: LAMP Server Desktop.
I got a free giveaway Dell desktop from my University, its probably a p4 or something. I was gonna throw Ubuntu on it and test with a LAMP server. That could work but I'd rather not have to lug a desktop to where I'll be working.

Option 2: MAMP Server on MBP.
This probably sounds the best to me, but I've never installed a MAMP server and I'd rather not clutter up my limited HDD space (although I doubt its really that much)

Option 3: ?????? Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're taking your MacBook Pro with you, just install MAMP on it. It consumes virtually no disk space and works perfectly.

Comment: can even install it on a flash drive it you really dont have the space